# Is it interesting to look at surface codes where the boundary conditions give the shape of a Mobius strip, Klein bottle, or the projective plane?

Tags: error-correction, surface-code

I was reading about the Toric code and how the boundary codes give it a shape of of a torus. Is it interesting to look at other ways to orient the edges of a square lattice? I.e. a mobius strip, Klein bottle, projective plane. Or are these not useful because objects like the Klein Bottle or projective plane don't exist in real life?

Comment: I think Hastings, Haah, and O'Donnell have recently done [exactly this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.03921) with a Klein bottle?  See also this [YouTube vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCizyHfXYss&t=286s) from O'Donnell, which seems pretty accessible.  (I think there are some questions about how this could be implemented on a quantum chip's layout though.)